# Query using $resource in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I want to make a query using a $resource in AngularJS such that I use a secondary characteristic of the table. I have a $resource which will give me all the Tweets... (all in coffeescript)

```
angular.module('resources.movies', ['ngResource'])

.factory("Tweet", ["$resource", "API_PREFIX", ($resource, API_PREFIX) ->
  $resource("#{API_PREFIX}/tweets/:id",
    {id: "@id"},
    update: {method: "PUT"}
  )
])
```

And in the controller (in coffeescript):

```
$scope.tweets = Tweets.query(recipientID: user.id)
```

I want to do something like SELECT * from Tweets where `tweet.recipientID = id`. It's not using the primary key (so it's not really restful). Can I do this?

Comment: You may be able to do $resource("#{API_PREFIX}/tweets/?recipientID=" + id, ...

Comment: you need to specify your query as method of your resource (as done with update) & you need an API endpoint for your query (#{API_PREFIX}/tweets/?recipientID=...)